# Visual Studio Code doesnt run on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I followed the instruction here https://askubuntu.com/questions/616075/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu to run Visual Studio Code https://code.visualstudio.com/

but nothing happens (no error message) when I double-click on application (named Code).

Comment: This would be better off in askubuntu or superuser.

Comment: No, this is on topic here.  But it is lacking in details.

Comment: Try running it from a terminal so you can see if it outputs an error message.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later Visual Studio Code should show up in Ubuntu Software application if you search for "vscode" or it can be installed from the terminal by running the command `sudo snap install code  --classic`. A snap in classic confinement behaves as a traditionally packaged application with full access to the system, and Visual Studio Code extensions are installed into the user's home directory.

Visual Studio Code is not an IDE, so it is not possible to create a project in Visual Studio Code, like it is in Visual Studio. On the other hand it is possible to run Python, C, C++, JavaScript, PHP, Java, R and some other programming language code blocks directly in Visual Studio Code using the Code Runner extension. Other extensions are required to get the debugging features of each programming language working.

Answer (score 0):

Where you extracted code, you cannot double click on it. Easiest way is to right-click and select run. You can make the "code" icon executable by using the terminal.